# Копировать часть html кода из массива jquery

Tags: jquery, массивы

Всем привет!

Есть массив jquery, в котором содержится набор элементов.

В массиве в том числе лежит такой элемент div class="title".../div.

Как найти этот div.title и вывести в нужном мне месте на странице?
При использовании $(массив).each('.title').appendTo('.modal-body') нужного результата я не получаю.

**Обновление 1**

Примерно эти объекты содержатся в массиве:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<a href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>

<div class="caption">

    <div class="title">
        <a href="/catalog/">МегаХрень 2000</a>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnailText">Универсальная дрель, которая может почти все</div>

    <div class="price">
        <div class="newPrice">12 533 р.</div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**Обновление 2**

Да, конечно, имена я изменил)

Если более подробно:
Есть некоторая функция, после клика выполняется следующее: я в переменную записываю содержимое, внутри

```
div.thumbnail
var purchase = $(this).closest('.thumbnail').clone();
```

код, который я привел выше, - это содержимое внутри этого блока div.
Мне нужно скопировать из этого кода `<div class="title">название товара</div>` и его цену `<div class="price"><div class="newPrice">99 рублей</div></div>`
и два этих куска поставить в всплывающее окно `div.modal-body`

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Что именно у вас является ключами массива? Каждый элемент, весь набор или что?

Comment: Возможно, Вам нужно сделать как-то так:

    $(array).filter('.title').appendTo($('.modal-body'));

Comment: К сожалению, скрипт в этом виде не срабатывает...

Comment: В таком случае вам нужно привести более подробный код, чтобы понять, какой вид имеет ваш массив.

Comment: Кстати, вместо array вы же подставили имя своего массива?

Comment: Попробуйте такой способ: var title = $(this).closest('.thumbnail').find('.title').html();
По идее в title будет лежать нужный вам текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4rouy2q3/